# New Colours for SharePoint calendar overlays

Tags: 2013, calendar, branding, overlay

I would like to change a couple of the 9 OOB colours for our SharePoint calendar overlays. I can do that by overriding the calendar CSS classes.

The parent calendar div does not get this class assigned as expected:

```
.ms-acal-color1
```

Instead it gets this class only:

```
.ms-acal-item
```

...which every overlay div has so i can't override the top one without explicitly defining each other class (.ms-acal-color1 - .ms-acal-color9)

Also, I'm not sure how to change the names in this drop down to match the new colours:

[image]

Comment: When I add the script to the webPart above the calendar, It changes the color fine BUT it takes away my calendar ribbon options. (Events, Calendar) Any ideas how to keep the ribbon from disappearing???

Answer (score 2):

Currently changing the colors listed in the drop down box within one site theme is not available, both in SharePoint Online and SharePoint

```
.ms-acal-color# {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #xxxxxx
}
.ms-acal-selcolor# {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #xxxxxx
}
.ms-acal-apanel-color# {
 BORDER-COLOR: #xxxxxx;
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #xxxxxx;
}
```

The above 3 classes of styles represent one color.So to change color you have to change above CSS

http://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/

Comment: Thanks, I followed that post but it doesn't address my questions. .ms-acal-color1 doesn't exist

Comment: Ok Can you just go to your color coded calendar.Edit that page and add HTML Form webpart and inside <style type=text\css></style>.Add following CSS

Comment: I can't because this has to be a global solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok Can you just go to your color coded calendar.Edit that page and add HTML Form webpart and inside 
`<style type=text\css></style>`.Add following CSS

```
.ms-acal-color3{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #C0362C
}

.ms-acal-selcolor3{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #C0362C
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color3{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #C0362C;
}

.ms-acal-color4{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #816C5B
}

.ms-acal-selcolor4{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #816C5B
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color4{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #816C5B;
}

.ms-acal-color8{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #668D3C
}

.ms-acal-selcolor8{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #668D3C
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color8{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #668D3C;
}

.ms-acal-color9{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #007996
}

.ms-acal-selcolor9{
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #007996
}

.ms-acal-apanel-color9{
 BORDER-COLOR: #C3B7AC; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #007996;
}
```

See if any changes are getting reflected

Comment: I believe you meant to say <style type=text/css></style> rather than <style type=text\css></style>. The direction of the slash is significant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way you set it up, using color1 as an example:

```
.ms-acal-apanel-color1, 
.ms-acal-color1 {
    background-color: #f19d00; // Orange;
}
```

This will change it both in the "Calendars in view" section of the Quick Launch and on the calendar itself. It took a bit of experimenting with the Web Inspector to nail it down. You can deploy an entirely new color scheme by creating a similar class for each color.