# How to add color in one of the choices in Calendar Overlay Settings?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I tried this code and put it into content editor, It only changes the color into red in the calendar

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-color1{
   background-color:red !important;
}
</style>​​​<br/>​<br/>
```

[image]
but in the "Calendars in view" it doesn't change into red (still green).

[image]

So I wanna add the red color in one of the choices.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add CSS to change the color of panel as below:

```
.ms-acal-apanel-color1{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: Where and how will I put that code, If i put that in the content editor, it doesn't work.

Comment: You are right. It has to be added in CEWP itself.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: Please add this CSS code below the CSS which you mentioned in question. Ref: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145209/new-colours-for-sharepoint-calendar-overlays